# How can I parameterize an SQL table without vulnerability to SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I'm writing a C# class library in which one of the features is the ability to create an empty data table that matches the schema of any existing table.

For example, this:

```
private DataTable RetrieveEmptyDataTable(string tableName)
{
    var table = new DataTable() { TableName = tableName };

    using var command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 0 * FROM {tableName}", _connection);
    using SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);

    return table;
}
```

The above code works, but it has a glaring security vulnerability: SQL injection.

My first instinct is to parameterize the query like so:

```
    using var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM @tableName", _connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
```

But this leads to the following exception:

> Must declare the table variable "@tableName"

After a quick search on Stack Overflow I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003241/must-declare-the-table-variable-table), which recommends using my first approach (the one with sqli vulnerability). That doesn't help at all, so I kept searching and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649925/parameterized-table-name), which says that the only secure solution would be to hard-code the possible tables. Again, this doesn't work for my class library which needs to work for arbitrary table names.

My question is this: how can I parameterize the table name without vulnerability to SQL injection?

Comment: SQL Server will not allow a paramerized table name - you have to do it about how you show it. At my last gig we came up with a number possible solutions (because the first query we did was "what database and what table contains the master data for this customer"). One solution we came up with was to have a specific table replacement call, with the table checked to see that it was in a list of tables in the database (from `sys.tables`, cached). In the end, we decided to accept the risk and keep it simple

Comment: @Flydog57 That's where I'm leaning right now as well. Maybe some sanitization attempts before it gets concatenated into the query

Comment: If you are like us, `tableName` is a string that we obtain from a table where we store customer metadata.  Because it was completely under our control and was untouched by user input or any other tainted data, the feeling what that there was no vulnerability and it wasn't worth adding complication.  I still wanted a to use a separate token format and a separate method in our data layer to do the table name replacement (it just bothered me the way it was).  I lost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arbitrary table name still has to exist, so you can check first that it does:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE name = @TableName)
BEGIN
  ... do your thing ...
END
```

And further, if the list of tables you want to allow the user to select from is known and finite, or matches a specific naming convention (like `dbo.Sales%`), or belongs to a specific schema (like `Reporting`), you could add additional predicates to check for those.

This requires you to pass the table name in as a proper parameter, not concatenate or token-replace. (And [please don't use `AddWithValue()` for anything](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), ever.)

Once your check that the object is real and valid has passed, then you will still have to build your SQL query dynamically, because you still won't be able to parameterize the table name. You still should apply `QUOTENAME()`, though, as I explain in these posts:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

So the final code would be something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectFromAnywhere
  @TableName sysname 
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects
      WHERE name = @TableName)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * 
      FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N';';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Nice try, robot.';
  END
END
GO
```

If you also want it to be in some defined list you can add

```
AND @TableName IN (N't1', N't2', …)
```

Or `LIKE <some pattern>` or join to `sys.schemas` or what have you.

Provided nobody has the rights to then modify the procedure to change the checks, there is no value you can pass to `@TableName` that will allow you to do anything malicious, other than maybe selecting from another table you didn’t expect because someone with too much access was able to create before calling the code. Replacing characters like `--` or `;` does not make this any safer.

Comment: I would also add to strip `; -- / *` characters. Or kick out when these found. If they have `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM {tableName}`, it can be now `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM sys.objects where 1=2; drop table Users`

Comment: @T.S. `QUOTENAME()` takes care of that, even in the case where someone managed to first create a table called `[sys.objects where 1=2; drop table Users]`, as it would first have to pass the check against `sys.objects`. You can strip characters if you like, but it's just extra work that doesn't offer any additional protection over (a) validating against the metadata and (b) using `QUOTENAME()`.

Comment: @T.S. As you can see, it works fine in fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8d8ff1914a222b5df58db95418a1ed9

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the table name to the SQL Server to apply [`quotename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on it to properly quote it and subsequently only use the quoted name.

Something along the lines of:

```
...

string quotedTableName = null;

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT quotename(@tablename);", connection))
{
    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@tablename", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128 /* nvarchar(128) is (currently) equivalent to sysname which doesn't seem to exist in SqlDbType */);
    parameter.Value = tableName;
    object buff = command.ExecuteScalar();
    if (buff != DBNull.Value
        && buff != null /* theoretically not possible since a FROM-less SELECT always returns a row */)
    {
        quotedTableName = buff.ToString();
    }
}

if (quotedTableName != null)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 0 FROM { quotedTableName };", connection))
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

(Or do the dynamic part on SQL Server directly, also using `quotename()`. But that seems overly and unnecessary tedious, especially if you will do more than one operation on the table in different places.)

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Bertrand's answer solved the problem, but a stored procedure is not useful for a class library that might interact with any database. Here is the way to write `RetrieveEmptyDataTable` (the method from my question) using his
answer:

```
private DataTable RetrieveEmptyDataTable(string tableName)
{
    const string tableNameParameter = "@TableName";
    var query =
        "  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects\n" +
        $"      WHERE name = {tableNameParameter})\n" +
        "  BEGIN\n" +
        "    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT TOP 0 * \n" +
        $"      FROM ' + QUOTENAME({tableNameParameter}) + N';';\n" +
        "    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;\n" +
        "END";


    using var command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(tableNameParameter, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tableName;
    using SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    var table = new DataTable() { TableName = tableName };
    Connect();
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    Disconnect();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: It's with several tables, not with "any database" - the issue I have with having that logic in the application code is that if I as a DBA want to make my checks more stringent I shouldn't have to modify code in a language I don't understand.

Comment: The purpose of my class library is to work for an arbitrary database. It's a stand-alone library. Not only would a DBA have no business messing with it, but if the library were closed source they wouldn't even be able to. I didn't state that in the question because it isn't relevant to the problem

Comment: You can of course solve the problem the same way without a stored procedure. My point is that the people responsible _for the database_ might have different goals (and different ideas about protection) than the author of the class library that accesses the database. :-)